# On the convergencce and limit of a peculiar sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

There is strong numerical evidence that the sequence $a_{n}:=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot ln(n+1-k)}{n\cdot (n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot ln(n)$ converges to $-\frac{3}{4}$: With a little program for the free software SageMath I have computed the following  table which shows in each line the index of a sequence member and its value:

$$\begin{aligned}
99996 -0.749935743704629\\
99997 -0.749935744297208\\
99998 -0.749935744889775\\
99999 -0.749935745482330\\
100000 -0.749935746074875\\
199996 -0.749966139521843\\
199997 -0.749966139678646\\
199998 -0.749966139835450\\
199999 -0.749966139992251\\
200000 -0.749966140149050\\
299996 -0.749976750698314\\
299997 -0.749976750770257\\
299998 -0.749976750842200\\
299999 -0.749976750914142\\
300000 -0.749976750986083\\
399996 -0.749982203469640\\
399997 -0.749982203511007\\
399998 -0.749982203552374\\
399999 -0.749982203593740\\
400000 -0.749982203635106\\
499996 -0.749985539656014\\
499997 -0.749985539682935\\
499998 -0.749985539709856\\
499999 -0.749985539736777\\
500000 -0.749985539763697\\
599996 -0.749987797792167\\
599997 -0.749987797811115\\
599998 -0.749987797830064\\
599999 -0.749987797849013\\
600000 -0.749987797867960\\
699996 -0.749989430865353\\
699997 -0.749989430879432\\
699998 -0.749989430893510\\
699999 -0.749989430907589\\
700000 -0.749989430921667\\
799996 -0.749990668555733\\
799997 -0.749990668566616\\
799998 -0.749990668577499\\
799999 -0.749990668588381\\
800000 -0.749990668599265\\
899996 -0.749991639951801\\
899997 -0.749991639960472\\
899998 -0.749991639969144\\
899999 -0.749991639977816\\
900000 -0.749991639986487\\
999996 -0.749992423279161\\
999997 -0.749992423286237\\
999998 -0.749992423293314\\
999999 -0.749992423300389\\
1000000 -0.74999242330746\\
\\
\end{aligned}$$

No matter how I came to investigate this peculiar sequence I regard as a real challenge to rigorously prove my conjecture or possibly disprove it but I would make a bet on it that it is true. On trying to give a proof I noticed that the numerator in the first term is kind of a discrete convolution of two sequences but could not really get on with this idea. Can anybody settle my question whether this sequence converges to $-\frac{3}{4}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k\cdot\ln(n+1-k)-k\cdot  \ln(n)  \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\cdot\ln\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)  \right)\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\cdot\ln\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)  \right)}_{\xrightarrow{n\to+\infty}\int_0^1x\ln(1-x)dx} \xrightarrow{n\to+\infty}1\cdot \left(-\frac{3}{4}  \right) = -\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Adam Rubinson  Two remarks: In the  Riemann sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\cdot f(\xi_{k})$ the point $xi_{k}$  you have the two different points $frac{k.1}{n}$ and $\frac{k}{n}$ int the same interval inserted into the function $x\cdot ln(1-x) $ at different places. Of course, this can be overcome easily. The second point is a bit more delicate as the integrand is not bounded in any neighborhood of $1%, so this is only an improper Riemann integral. But using Lebesgue integration theory it can be shown that this Riemann sum still converges to the  improper Riemann integral.